# Simple Nutch 1.3/Solr index explanation

Tags: solr, nutch

After much searching, it doesn't seem like there's any straightforward explanation of how to use Nutch 1.3 with Solr.

I have a Solr index with other content in it that I'll be using on a website for search.

I'd like to add Nutch results to the index, which will add external sites to the website's search.

All of this is working just fine.

The question is, how do you freshen the index? Do you have to delete all of the Nutch results from Solr first? Or does Nutch take care of that? Does Nutch remove results that are no longer valid from the Solr index?

Shell scripts with no documentation or explanation of what they are doing haven't been helpful with answering these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nutch schema defines id (= url) as teh unique key. If you re-crawl the url teh document will be replaced in solr index when nutch posts the data to solr.

Comment: How does it prune documents that are no longer on the website it crawled?

Comment: That would not happen by default. To achieve that you would need to dlete all results for the site from the index and then run a refresh crawl. The delete can be done just before submiting new data to the  solr index so that you have the results until the refresh crawl is completed.

Comment: Is that something nutch can do? I'm not seeing anything about deleting things out of the index.

Comment: check out solr documentation for deleting documents at : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query you can post something like <delete>host:xyz.com</delete> to the same solr index you have setup for nutch.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to implement incremental crawling in Nutch...   which is dependent on your application. Some people want to recrawl every day, others every 3 month. The max is 90 days in any case.

The general idea is to delete crawl segments that are older than your max time for recrawl, since they will be redundant at that time. And produce a fresh `solrindex` for use in Solr.

I'm afraid that you have to do that yourself in scripting. One day I may put on the wiki some scripts I did for that, but they are not ready for publish as it stands.

Answer (score -1):

Try Lucidworks' enterprise Solr for testing/prototyping, which has a webcrawler builtin.

http://www.lucidimagination.com/products/lucidworks-search-platform/enterprise

It'll give you a feel for the whole Lucene stack. It has a MUCH better interface than any other Java software I've ever used. It's a joy to use.